# How to disable the Expansion of parent(i mean dispalying child) on double click of parent in TreeView?

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, treeview, radtreeview

I am working on silverlight and i am under a situation where i had to disable the arrow symbol of parent  RadTreeView `("<")`.

I succesfully done it by doing so (using `ExpanderStyle`):

```
<telerik:RadTreeView  Name="RadTreeViewObj"  **ExpanderStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderStyle}"**   VerticalAlignment="Top"   Background="{StaticResource BGBrush_1}" .....>
```

and then i do something like this:

```
  <Style x:Key="ExpanderStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />

            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Doing this **disappears** the arrow. **But not Disables.** I mean when i double click around the parent area it still hides and displays the children.

**How to make it disable ?** (it should not hide or display on clicking the Parent area on double  click).It should always display the children (with out arrow symbol) but should not collapse or uncollapse on double click over parent area.

**In short i want to avoid collapsing and spreading of Parent doble click. How to do that ?**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
IsExpandOnDblClickEnabled="False"
```

done the job.